# Structure of a sentence from The War of the Worlds

Tags: inversion

> You know how that blackness looks on a frosty starlight night. In a
> telescope it seems far profounder. And invisible to me because it was
> so remote and small, flying swiftly and steadily towards me across
> that incredible distance, drawing nearer every minute by so many
> thousands of miles, ***came the Thing*** they were sending us, the Thing
> that was to bring so much struggle and calamity and death to the
> earth.

The word order confuses me. Why is an inversion (OR is it?) used here?

Comment: This structure, putting the verb ahead of the subject, is common, particularly in dramatic situations, as a means of emphasising the dramatic effect. **Out of the mist loomed a giant shadow**. **Out of his mouth came words I never want to hear again**.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. What actually confuses me is the absence of the part that is supposed to precede the verb, as, in your examples, "out of the mist" and "out of his mouth." OR is it the whole thing starting from "invisible?"

Comment: It is the whole thing starting from _And invisible_

Comment: @mdewey Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Various word-orders are possible. "Then came news from France", "Then from France came news", "Then news came from France", "Then news from France came" and, poetically, dramatically and unusually, "Came the news from France", which is the structure used in your extract.

If we simplify it, the main clause in your quotation becomes, "And came the Thing." We often say, for example, ***Then** came the surprise*, but ***And** came...* is rarely, if ever, used. The meaning is clear though.

For dramatic effect we sometimes turn to an old-sounding word or structure. If it sounds Biblical, all the better. We don't say 'Behold!' in normal conversation, but it can be either amusing or portentous to use it in, for example,

> *Behold! The leader of the free world!*

Similarly, sports commentators are fond of the expression,

> *Cometh (ie 'comes') the hour, cometh the man!*

It is dramatic because it sounds Biblical. And we certainly wouldn't say "Comes six o'clock" in normal conversation. I think that is why Wells wrote what he did. "And came the Thing" is unfamiliar, unnerving and dramatic. It might not be grammatically correct, but great writers break the rules!